# Error in updating objects in Parse with error code 101 (Happened after xcode7 update)

Tags: ios, parse-platform, swift2, xcode7

In my iOS app, there is an object on the table and I coded in a way that the taken photo should be uploaded if the object on the tableview is clicked. It worked fine until I upgraded to Xcode7.
Here is the code.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
 if indexPath.row == 0 {
for var n = 0; n < self.posts.count; ++n {
                        self.posts[n].forEvent = cityEvent
                        self.cityEvent!.lastlyUpdatedAt = self.posts[self.posts.count - 1].takenAt}}

PFObject.saveAllInBackground(self.posts, block: { (success, error) -> Void in
   if success == false {
        //show alertview with errors
}
}
```

Whenever I try to update objects it gives me an error saying "[Error]: object not found for update (Code: 101, Version: 1.9.0)".

I was looking over other posts related to this and it was either "objects do not exist" or "problems with ACL setting". I am sure objects do exist because I was setting a breakpoint and checked that it exists.

Regards ACL, my setting is like following:

```
let acl = PFACL()
    acl.setPublicReadAccess(true)
    PFACL.setDefaultACL(acl, withAccessForCurrentUser: true)
```

I am pretty sure there is nothing wrong with ACL setting...
This leaves me absolutely no idea how to tackle this problem.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the type of the `posts` variable ?

Comment: @MoNazemi it is an array which holds image and video files in form of PFfile (Parse's file format)

Comment: So the array type is PFFile ??

Comment: yeah, its tye is PFFile

Comment: So you are sending an array of PFFiles to a function that expects an array of PFObjects ??! Obviously there is no object in a PFFile !

Comment: Never mind. I scratch out what I said. Sry. The objects inside self.posts are indeed in form of PFObject and they each has PFFile column to store either photo or video. Sorry for the confusion